# Estimate convergence order of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, rate-of-convergence

For a given real sequence $\{a_k\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, suppose the sequence satisfies relation $| a_k - a_{k-1} | \le \frac 1 k$. We know this does not guarantee the sequence to be Cauchy. If we take $a_k = \sum_{j=1}^k \frac 1 j$, the sequence is apparently divergent.

I am wondering if we know a priori that the sequence converges to a limit point $\lim_{k \to \infty} a_k = a$. Would the relation $|a_k - a_{k-1} | \le \frac 1 k$ provide any interesting information about the sequence? For example, the rate of convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the limit of $a_k$ does not exist (diverges to $\pm\infty$ or oscillates) this would tell you that with convergence rate no slower than $1/k$

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{a_k}{k} = 0$$.

You can prove with Cesaro-Stolz theorem:

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{a_k}{k} = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{a_k - a_{k-1}}{k - (k-1)} = \lim_{k \to \infty}(a_k - a_{k-1}) = 0$$

Comment: A little confused by what you meant. If the sequence converges faster (no slower) than $1/k$. Should it be $\lim_{k \to \infty} (a_k - a)/(1/k) = \mathcal O(1)$? That is, the sequence $k(a_k - a)$ is bounded for all $k$. It is more like you proved $a_k$ grows no faster than $k$.

Comment: I mean that the consequence is $a_k/k \to 0$ no slower than $1/k$.  Its just a piece of information, since your question is not looking for a specific answer.